# Webviews are visible if using .app file generated from local xcode but not working on using IPA/.app file generated from CI or apple app store

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios

## this code works fine on running .app file which generated from local .app but not able to fetch webview on running .app/IPA file from hockeyapp ior app store

```
def switch_context(context, next_element)
   puts "Starts switching context"
   puts available_contexts
   #binding.pry
   contexts = available_contexts
   i = 1
   if context == 'native'
     set_context("NATIVE_APP")
   else
     begin
       while i < contexts.size
         puts "Webview switching starting from front"
         puts "Switching to new context #{i}"
         set_context(available_contexts[i])
         i += 1
         sleep 1
         is_present = exists {find_element(:xpath, "//*[@id='#{next_element}']")}
         puts "Element is #{is_present} present"
         if is_present #check if context has web element
           puts "Context found"
           break
         end
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you able to launch the app?

Comment: Yes I'm able to launch the app it's just I'm not able to get webviews on hybrid page on install ios app via IPA but working fine with .app (generated from local xcode)